# CodeIgniter - sending variable from controller to a view which use template

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have the following problems.

I am using the following template for my application:

```
<?php $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_header_in');?>

<?php $this->load->view($bo_main_content);?>

<?php $this->load->view('backOffice/bo_footer_in');?>
```

When I send data from the controller, to edit a record, I have the following code:

```
$data['userid'] = $this->back_office_users->getOneUser($userid);
$data['bo_main_content'] = "backOffice/edituser_view";
$this->load->view('backOffice/bo_template_in', $data);
```

Now, in my view, where I want to edit the record, I am getting it all right, my form is filled with the user name and password but.... on the top of the page, I get displayed the userid, username, userpassword, which is not what I want. Can anyone help me how can I send the data from my controller to my view, so I can have only my form filled, and not have the userid,username and password diplayed on the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

What you have shown looks ok. Search your models/controllers for a var_dump and re-look at the code in your view for a print_r. I typically do this during development to see the variable contents.